# How do I uncompress LOTS of gifs

Tags: java, gif, image-compression

I was writing a java program that was displaying gifs but the gifs that were being used were apparently compressed and that causes the GIF display to flicker. Is there any way I can make a program to uncompress the gifs. I found a website https://ezgif.com/repair but that only allows one image at a time and I have 1600 and I do not have the time to uncompress every one of them individually. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Q: Is there any way I can make a program to uncompress the gifs. A: Yes. Start coding. Hint: You may wish to rephrase your question in a way that attracts usable information. As it stands, your question isn't really a question at all. Start by asking about some specific issue you're worried about in your attempt to write your program.

Comment: Check out this javascript library [gifshot.js](https://github.com/yahoo/gifshot)

Comment: Is this another of those Java != JavaScript questions?

Comment: This program is in java, not javascript so I don't know why you recommended a javascript library, I can't use it. And if there is a way then could you please state it because if I had that I could start working on a program but I do not know of any java library that can help me uncompress gifs so please enlighten me.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.nayuki.io/page/gif-optimizer-java) is worth a look? It's scriptable, at least.